# This system lacks PPP kernel support

Tags: debian, ppp

I bought a VPS from hostinger.com. Now I'm trying to set VPN connection to another server using PPP, but I have an error:

> Sorry - this system lacks PPP kernel support

I tried different versions: Debian 8, 9 and Ubuntu 18.04 (Linux xxx.local 4.15.0) but I always had the same error.

What can I do to "add support" for PPP?

Comment: I got only server VPN IP, login and password. I don't know what they use for VPN server. So if PPP is not a good way to connect.. what should I use?

Comment: `modprobe ppp` or something like that? See if you can find any ppp modules in `/lib/modules` ... and look for anything mentioning PPP in `/proc/config.gz` if you have one

Comment: @roaima True indeed...in the back of my mind I knew it was something off. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked, "*What can I do to "add support" for PPP?*".

Really this should be a case of asking your hosting provider. It may be that they won't support PPP because you've rented a VPS and they need to use a generic shared kernel.

You [then asked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478065/this-system-lacks-ppp-kernel-support?noredirect=1#comment873856_478065) "*So if PPP is not a good way to connect.. what should I use?*".

PPP is not a routeable protocol. To use PPP across the Internet one typically encapsulates it in either L2TP or PPTP.

If you want to steer away from L2TP/PPTP then you could choose something like OpenVPN or IPSec. Of these two, OpenVPN is (IMO) far easier to set up as a point-to-point link than IPSec.